# Catch errors sent to browser console by jQuery

Tags: jquery, rest, typescript

I am using jQuery to consume a RESTful web service. The call is wrapped inside a Promise that resolves or rejects depending on whether the web service could be reached or not. The call works perfectly and so does the Promise. But when the web service is not reachable, an error message is sent to the console. Is there anyway to avoid that message?

My TypeScript class:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
import { Version } from "../model/Version";

export class SiteService {
    constructor() { }

    public requestRestServiceVersion(): Promise<Version> {
        return $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/myproj/rest/version"
        });
    }
}
```

The error message I would like to disappear:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/myproj/rest/version net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED        jquery.js:9600
```

Comment: That is probably a browser based error, not a javascript one. Also wrapping `$.ajax` in new Promise is an anti-pattern since `$.ajax` already returns a thenable promise

Comment: @charlietfl Ok, thanks for the Promise advice. Indeed it was done double. I updated the post. Still, even if this is a browser based error, is there a way to not show that message in the browser console?

Comment: Only by disabling monitoring XMLHttp requests in dev tools

Comment: @charlietfl You mean within the browser or within JavaScript code?

Comment: No within browser dev tools options settings